# Auto form filling

Tags: forms, automation, imacros

I have a requirement like I need to fill an online form automatically. (Auto form filling).

Means I need to create an application in which clicking on the "Auto fill” button it will open the form in browser (form is another website page) and fill the data automatically.

The data (which may change each time) I will supply from my application. So first I thought of implementing the functionality using iMacro.

But later I realized I can’t call this imacro from an application if it is free version.  So please suggest me some idea to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i under stand your problem i would say  try [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)  ..it just a simple you can say a compiler and a language which uses image recognition and you can make autobot through this and a very easy to learn ..

Comment: thanks for the reply..mine is dot net application.. so it is possible to ues sikuli in that?